# Spring Session with Redis - server.session.timeout has no effect

Tags: spring, session, redis, timeout, spring-session

I follow this documentation to set up sessions in my Spring Boot application: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html

application.properties

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
server.session.timeout=10
```

After sending in a request, I see the following records in redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "spring:session:sessions:4b524c1e-e133-4d04-8b5b-40ffc3685af3"
2) "spring:session:sessions:expires:c1e2792f-f001-4a02-b812-39ab68f719ea"
3) "spring:session:sessions:expires:4b524c1e-e133-4d04-8b5b-40ffc3685af3"
4) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:105121963489487663346"
5) "spring:session:expirations:1521492480000"
```

I expect these records to disappear after 10 seconds (because of the server.session.timeout property), but the data stays even after several minutes.

How to set up session time out in Spring Sessions properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a deprecated `server.session.timeout` which was replaced with `server.servlet.session.timeout` in Spring Boot 2.0. With the change from [PR I've opened against your sample repo](https://github.com/nagyzsolthun/spring-boot-session-timeout/pull/1) the desired session timeout is applied correctly.

Please take time to get familiar with [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) and consider using `spring-boot-properties-migrator` module.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Vedran answer is not completely correct, because the Springboot common properties has the two properties, both are currently active and not deprecated.

[Springboot common properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

**For Spring Session:**

```
spring.session.timeout= # Session timeout. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
```

**For web propeties**

WEB PROPERTIES
EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)

```
server.servlet.session.timeout= # Session timeout. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, but unfortunately, I can't effectively control the session timeout by setting "spring.session.timeout" and "server.servlet.session.timeout".
My solution is to configure the session timeout through annotations.

```java
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 30)
```