# Spring Session with Redis - keys are not getting expired in Redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am new to `spring-data-redis`. I have integrated with a spring-boot application. As part of this, I have added a few configs as follows:

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.session.redis.namespace=tc
server.servlet.session.timeout=5h
```

But even after having the expiry timeout as 5 hrs, I see all records which are months old, in redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
  1) "tc:expirations:1653887100000"
  2) "tc:sessions:2a4d193c-612b-48b6-8b7a-3ac525aba2d4"
  3) "tc:sessions:fd10e891-357a-4cd4-a14b-58a1bb2e16ae"
  4) "tc:sessions:expires:99969082-b0bc-4122-9511-1aba098a0eb7"
  5) "tc:sessions:expires:b9a84856-9971-4e9e-bfec-9037ceb7d317"
  6) "tc:expirations:1653897300000"
  7) "tc:sessions:expires:b8c9969c-6bde-4aca-8d2e-7510d90f9706"
  8) "tc:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:abcd"
```

In this context, I have gone through: [Spring Session with Redis - server.session.timeout has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371783/spring-session-with-redis-server-session-timeout-has-no-effect) and I see I have done exactly the same as the accepted answer suggested. So I am not sure, what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a configuration i've done on my project with Spring session and Redis
The timeout should be set on spring session parameters

*Sorry for the yaml... :) *

```yaml
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  session:
    store-type: redis
    timeout: 3000
    redis:
      namespace: spring:session
      flush-mode: on_save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `@EnableRedisHttpSession` annotation you need to set `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds` like:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 86400)
```